# What are drawbacks of pip's --no-compile flag?

Tags: python, pip

It seems that compiling Python files to byte code takes a significant amount of time during package installation with pip. Is there any disadvantage of using the `--no-compile` flag?

I am specifically interested in CI systems where environment recreation happens all the time. Is it less efficient to generate the byte code on import instead of during package installation? It seems to me as if only compiling the modules that are actually used should lead to speedups of CI pipelines.

Comment: In a CI pipeline where the installed (v)env is not reused/cached, it might well be a good idea to use `--no-compile`.